# First go at CoreData. Am I doing this right?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

A little background. I have an app that has historically used NSUserDefaults to store settings. This has caused me many issues since I am storing critical activation values and NSUserDefaults appears to get wiped out sometimes, but that is another topic. I am going to transition to using CoreData and I want to make sure I am approaching this correctly.

I've built an entity called Registry that has an attribute of key and one attribute for each possible data type. The idea is key-value pairs similar to how you would use NSUserDefaults to store key-value pairs. So my model looks like this:

[image: Model]

I created a subclass of NSManagedObjectModel. From what I can tell, it is not necessary to do this and the only advantage it gets you is a little cleaner code. Is that correct?

So I wrote a little test segment of code to see if I am actually getting how this works. I am not doing any error handling which I would obviously do in real life code, this is just to get a general understanding. [EDIT: With all the comments about proper error handling, I thought I would update so errors are properly handled. Hopefully this will help other viewers to learn also]

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Registry"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"key == %@", @"Test"];
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate;
NSError *coreDataError;
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&coreDataError];
if (coreDataError != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error in executeFetchRequest: %@\r\n%@", coreDataError, coreDataError.userInfo);
}

Registry *testSetting1;

if ([fetchedObjects count] == 1) {
    testSetting1 = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"Value of Test = %@", testSetting1.stringVal);
}
else{
    testSetting1 = [NSEntityDescription
                    insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Registry"
                    inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    testSetting1.key = @"Test";
    testSetting1.stringVal = @"ABC123";
    [self.managedObjectContext save:&coreDataError];
    if (coreDataError != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error in managedObjectContext save: %@\r\n%@", coreDataError, coreDataError.userInfo);
    }
}
```

This seems to work, my settings are persisting like they are supposed to. I just want to make sure I am completely understanding how this works. Please don't reply saying to read the Apple documentation, I have already. I just would like you guys to grade my homework :)

If correct, my next steps will be to write a wrapper around all of this for a little more convenience.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem you're experiencing or the reason you think something might be wrong?

Comment: Basically, there are some scenarios where my app will crash that I have not hunted down yet. Obviously I need to fix this, but in the mean time I cannot keep having user settings wiped out when the app crashes, it creates a support nightmare. It is not every time, in fact most times if the app crashes NSUserDefaults are fine. But I think if the crash occurs during a synchronize the plist attached to NSUserDefaults becomes corrupt.

Comment: The screenshot is too small, can't see anything. Could you post a larger image?

Comment: Updated the screen shot, should now be readable. Sorry about that.

Comment: Do not pass nil for the error (doing the save) and log what the problem could be.

Comment: Yes, I absolutely agree, flex. This is just a small amount of code to verify my understanding, when I begin implementing for production I will handle my errors. Thanks!

Comment: Also create an object in a simpler manner. See *Creating a Managed Object* https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/articles/cdCreateMOs.html.

Comment: What about your problem?

Comment: So that would be how to create my ManagedObject without subclassing, correct?

Comment: Ah, I see. There is not a problem with anything above. This is just a new topic for me and I want to make sure I have properly grasped the concept. The problem I am solving for is that I am losing NSUserDefaults if my app crashes for an unknown reason. The path I am taking to resolve is migrating to Core Data.

Comment: There's a [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) site for asking for suggestions when your code works.

Comment: I did not know that existed, I will absolutely use that in the future. Thanks, Caleb.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a code review.

Answer (score 7):

You are not catching and dealing with errors.  This is **VERY** bad behavior for a developer.  Every time you see a place to pass an error pointer you should pass an error and then check to see if the error condition happened.

Even if you just print the error to `NSLog()` you **must** check the error otherwise you are asking for pain.

When you call `-executeFetchRequest:error:` capture the error.  If the return is `nil` then there is an error.  Print that error out.

When you call `-save:` capture the error.  If the call returns `NO` then there is an error. Print that error out.

If I were a teacher I would mark down severely for that as it is a hidden problem waiting to bite you.

Comment: Thanks, Marcus.
I definitely agree with you. Once I begin to implement into my app I will handle my errors like I do elsewhere. The code above is to show the concept.

Comment: Even in concept (I do it even in presentations); check the error and print it to `NSLog()`.  Always do it, even when the code will never be run. If you add the check 100% of the time you will never forget and develop a bad habit.

Comment: I can buy into that. I will update the post with error handling.

Answer (score 3):

You're using an incorrect `NSError` idiom. Check the return result, then look at `NSError` if result is nil.

```
    NSError *coreDataError;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&coreDataError];
    if (!fetchedObjects) {
        NSLog(@"Error in executeFetchRequest: %@\r\n%@", coreDataError, coreDataError.userInfo);
    }
```

and

```
    BOOL saveOK = [self.managedObjectContext save:&coreDataError];
    if (!saveOK) {
        NSLog(@"Error in managedObjectContext save: %@\r\n%@", coreDataError, coreDataError.userInfo);
    }
```

I'm also skeptical of this line:

```
if ([fetchedObjects count] == 1) {
```

Is there any chance at all that you could have duplicate entries for a key? If so, then once you have one duplicate, you will have many (because then `fetchedObjects.count > 1` forever). How about

```
if ([fetchedObjects count] >= 1) {
```

instead?

Comment: I find the error handling portion interesting. I have always handled errors by checking if the passed error is nil after the call, I am struggling to think of instances where a result of false would be passed and error would be anything but nil, and vice versa. As for the checking of the array count, the wrapper I am writing around this will be looking for the key before it writes a new one, so there should only ever be one result. This particular data model should only ever support one result.

Comment: @KyleJurick: Hal is right, and is is documented in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/ErrorHandling/ErrorHandling.html: *"When dealing with errors passed by reference, it’s important to test the return value of the method to see whether an error occurred, as shown above. Don’t just test to see whether the error pointer was set to point to an error."*

Comment: Very good, glad that I posted this. Thanks guys.

Comment: Think of the pointer you passed in for the `NSError` as a scratch pad.  The framework will use it, setting it in advance of an actual failure.  When a merge happens is a perfect example.  If a merge is detected the error can get populated but if the merge resolves itself the framework doesn't clear the error, it just continues on leaving the error pointer "dirty".

Answer (score 2):

The line `[self.managedObjectContext insertObject:testSetting1];` is not necessary, the `Registry` is inserted into that context at the time of creation.

You only need to insert it like that if you pass a `nil` context at the time of creation.

Other than that, it seems OK to me.

Comment: Interesting that calling insert like I did did not cause a duplicate entry.

Comment: Because the `NSManagedObjectContext` knew that the `NSManagedObject` was already inserted.